# best way to download, process, and concat into TFRecords using dask

Tags: python, multiprocessing, dask

I need to download images, run some image processing on them, and then pack them into `n` TFRecords (e.g. 100 images per TFRecord).

Doing this with python Queues I would have have `d` download threads, `p` worker processes that process the images, and then have `w` worker processes that would be writing the images with TFRecordWriter when they are available.

I'd like to try this with `dask` so I have something like:

```
urls = bag.from_sequence(images_urls)
processed = urls.map(download_image).map(process)
by2 = processed.repartition(2).map_partitions(packing)
by3 = processed.repartition(3).map_partitions(packing)
bag.concat([by2, by3]).compute()
```

The issue with the above is that the `map_partitions` does not appear to get the images in a streaming fashion. The entire partition appears to be in memory before the `packing` function is called on the partition.

The other annoyance with the above is that I see no way in `dask` to finely control what part of the dag gets scheduled where. The downloader can happen with a thread scheduler where the processing and packer parts needs to happen in different processes. Is this possible or are you stuck with sticking with a type of scheduler across the entire graph?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not want several images to be loaded in a batch by `bag`, then you could construct your bag to have just one item per partition (since you know the number of URLs beforehand). All the inputs for any given task do indeed need to be in memory of a worker before that worker can execute the given task.

Maybe simpler approach is to drop back to using the `delayed` syntax, something like

```
ims = [dask.delayed(download_image)(url) for url in images_urls]
processed = [dask.delayed(process)(im) for im in ims]
packs = [dask.delayed(packing)(processed[n:n+100]) for n in
         range(0, len(processed), 100)]
dask.compute(packs)
```

Indeed, you can only have one scheduler to execute the graph, but Dask will tryt o scheduler tasks to run in the location where the data was loaded.

Comment: With this approach the packing is still only called once all of the processing has taken place. This means that all of the images are in memory and we are not streaming to disk as they are processed, as desired. I think there is a fundamental mismatch between these APIs and what I'm trying to do. Everything is great up until this last step.. I would want to turn the delays into futures and block in a writing thread or something.

Comment: I found that I can convert a list of delays to futures by using the dask distributed client: futures = client.compute(delays)... However the futures always remain in pending state.

Comment: Okay, the pending future was an issue with my local state. Converting the delays to futures allows me to stream as needed. Thanks!